# How do I stop Adblock Plus from intercepting Crtl+Shift+V in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, adblock

Normally, Crtl+Shift+V means "paste text without formatting". When I install Adblock Plus or Adblock Edge in Firefox, it intercepts this keystroke to show some of its UI. There is no configuration option to turn that off that I can find. What do I do, short of uninstalling Adblock?

Comment: Actually there is a configuration for the extension: https://adblockplus.org/en/faq_customization#shortcuts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Type `about:config` in your browser address bar
2. Click on `i'll be careful, I promise!` button and continue
3. In the upcoming settings, navigate to `extensions.adblockplus.sidebar_key`
4. In the upcoming pop-up erase and type the new string (Shortcut)
5. Once you change the status you would see the columns changed as

   Status = User Set

   Type   = String (depends upon the string/shortcut you gave)

   value  = your defined value (i.e new shortcut)
6. Close the window
7. Restart the browser to make the changes take effect

For additional reference you can refer [here](https://adblockplus.org/en/faq_customization#shortcuts)